# What UML element must be used to show JPMS module on class diagram?

Tags: java, uml, java-9, java-module

I am trying to show on my UML class diagram two JPMS modules and inside them packages and classes. The problem is I can't understand what element to use to show module. Please, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **In UML**:

there are **Packages** and **Components**.

**Package**:  see [reference 1](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html)

> Package is a namespace **used to group together elements** that are
>   semantically related and might change together. It is a general
>   purpose mechanism to organize elements into groups to provide **better**
>   **structure** for **system model**.

and in [reference 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(UML)):

> Pretty much all UML elements can be grouped into packages. Thus,
>   classes, objects, use cases, components, nodes, node instances etc.
>   can all be organized as packages, thus enabling a manageable
>   organization of the myriad elements that a real-world UML model
>   entails.

**Components**:  see [reference 3](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component.html)

> A component is a class representing a **modular part of a system** with
>   encapsulated content and whose manifestation is replaceable within its
>   environment.
>
> A component has its **behavior** defined in terms of **provided interfaces**
>   and **required interfaces** (potentially exposed via ports).
>
> Component serves **as a type** whose conformance is defined by these
>   provided and required interfaces (encompassing both their static as
>   well as dynamic semantics). One component may therefore be substituted
>   by another only if the two are type conformant.

### **In Java 9:**

reference: book: Java 9 Modularity Revealed, Alexandru Jecan, 2017, page 5

**Characteristics of a Module**:

> Some of the characteristics of a **module** include the following:
>
> - A module **must define interfaces** for **communication** with other modules.
> - A module defines a separation between the **module interface** and the **module implementation**.
> - A module should present a **set of properties** that contain information.
> - Two or more modules can be nested together.
> - A module should have a clear, defined responsibility. Each function should be implemented by only one module.
> - A module must be able to be **tested** independently from other modules.
> - An error in a module should not propagate to other modules.

**Therefor:** 
Java 9 JPMS modules should be shown by UML Components. We can not use UML Packages to model a Java 9 Module. UML packages is used to model Java packages. And we all know, there is huge difference between Java 9 packages and modules.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to design your system. When you consider the JMPS modules as closed elements having defined interfaces, then component is the correct model element. I.e., you apply the encapsulation principle. If you consider them as containers, that just contain some elements and you want to use these inner elements directly, then a package is the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ll have to use a package to represent the JPMS module, maybe stereotype it with “JPMS Module” or something to add more meaning. It doesn’t sound like a JPMS module is a class or interface etc. so I don’t think there’s anything else that you could use from UML Class models to represent this.

Comment: The question was whether this could be modeled in UML Class diagrams. Components are not in the Class diagram language, they’re part of component diagrams. I’d agree that Component would be a better representation but that’s not what was asked.

Comment: a Component is a type, you can put components into Class Diagram too. see [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/index.html), **The basics** paragraph.

Comment: Hey, yea I’m aware of the MOF. My logic is- typically in a class diagram you’re modelling information structure (eg domain, pim, OO code structure, table structure) & in component diagram you’re modelling component structure. What you’re doing putting both on the same diagram is mixing purposes, unless of course your purpose is only to show traceability, which may be the case here. I’m not convinced though, hence my original answer. I suppose Pavel_k could elaborate the need.